# Multivalued cookies, not so multivalue?

Tags: asp.net, httpcookie

My cookie does seem to create itself and it does store value, but only the last value, so basically it always holds 1 item, and when I try to add another it simply replaces the 1 item. 
My code is below, any ideas are appreciated.

```
    if (Request.Cookies["CartData"] == null)
    {
        HttpCookie NewCookie = new HttpCookie("CartData");
        Response.Cookies.Add(NewCookie);
    }
    /* Process Queries */
        int Qty;
        if (Request.QueryString["Action"] == "AddToCart")
        {
            string ProductID = Request.QueryString["ProductID"];
            string ProductCategory = Request.QueryString["Category"];

            /* Check if Quantity entered is a valid number, if not set to 1 */
            if (!int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["Qty"], out Qty))
            {
                Qty = 1;
            }

            /* Check if the item already exists in Cart */
            if (Request.Cookies["CartData"][ProductID + "_" + ProductCategory] != null)
            {
                int tempQty;
                tempQty = int.Parse(Request.Cookies["CartData"][ProductID + "," + ProductCategory]);
                tempQty += Qty;
                Response.Cookies["CartData"][ProductID + "_" + ProductCategory] = tempQty.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Cookies["CartData"][ProductID + "_" + ProductCategory] = Qty.ToString();
            }
            Response.Cookies["CartData"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code when Requesting you use

```
Request.Cookies["CartData"][ProductID + "," + ProductCategory])
```

while when writing you use

```
Response.Cookies["CartData"][ProductID + "_" + ProductCategory]
```

so you should replace , by _ in the parameter.

Is there any reason not to use Session for this?

Comment: Thanks Olaf, that does help, although my application still seems to hold one item. I noticed however that if I keep adding the same item, quantity does go up! Its only when I add another item does it reset, can it be because cookies are rewritten every-time and cannot be updated? PS: I know how to do this in session, I just wanted to practice my cookie skills before I go and write my ASP.NET Certification. :D

Comment: No, they should not be rewritten. I can't see why that happens. Try the following: use Cookies[ProductID + "_" + ProductCategory] instead of Cookies["CartData"][ProductID + "_" + ProductCategory]. Then you get of the multidimnensional array, and it is easier to check if there is any other error.